# Hiding a field for a subtype in Alloy

Tags: overloading, subtype, alloy

Suppose I have the following signature declarations, in Alloy 4.2:

```
sig Target {}

abstract sig A {
    parent: lone A,
    r: some Target
}

sig B extends A {}
sig C extends A {}
```

When running, the resulting instances would have arrows from every `B` to some `Target`, and from `C` to some `Target`.

How would I be able to hide only the arrows from `B`?
I tried the following, at first:

```
abstract sig A {
    parent: lone A
}

sig B extends A {
    r: some Target
}

sig C extends A {
    r: some Target
}
```

This would give me control over `r` in `B`, but it introduces a lot of ambiguity when writing properties. I would like to keep these as simple as possible. For example:

```
all a: A | a.r = parent.a.r
```

The above says that `a`'s `Targets` is the set of `a`'s children's `Targets`.
With the latter declarations, I would have to rewrite this to

```
all b: B | b.r = parent.b.((B <: r) + (C <: r))
all c: C | c.r = parent.c.((B <: r) + (C <: r))
```

which is undesirable.

Is there any workaround to be able to have a *general* field, but still have control over what arrows are displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function that exactly corresponds to (C <: r):

```
fun C_r : A -> Target {
    (C <: r)
}
```

In the Alloy visualizer, you wil have access to relation $C_r. Then, you can turn off "Show as arcs" for relation r, but still have $C_r visible. This should hide the set of edges that belong to (B <: r).

Comment: Thanks, Eunsuk, that answered my question. I've done similiar things before, using functions for special cases of relations (e.g.: coloring atoms in the graph coloring problem), but, for some reason, only overloading came to my mind!